# How to add images to UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I temporarly added some values to the `UITableViewCell` programmatically. But I need to add images to each cell. How can I do that?

Here is my code. .h file

```
 @interface BidalertsViewController : UIViewController       <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *listData;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData; 
@end
```

.m file

```
 @synthesize listData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,310,28)];
newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UITextView *mytext = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 25.0)];
mytext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mytext.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mytext.editable = NO;
mytext.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
mytext.text = @"Asset Name";
[mytext release];
[newView addSubview:mytext];

[self.view addSubview:newView];
[newView release];


NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPod", @"iPad",nil];
self.listData = array;
[array release];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
 - (void)dealloc {
  [listData dealloc];
  [super dealloc];
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [self.listData count];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row]; 
return cell;

UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
[imv release];
 }
@end
```

The code didn't add images to the cell. What's the problem? How can I do to add custom image to cell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move `return cell;` at the end of the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row]; 


    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
    [imv release];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: image is displayed. but image is displayed in front of text. text is not shown fully.

Comment: it's work properly because `textLabel` has frame which intersects with your `UIImageView`. Probably you need for custom cell.

Answer (score 7):

You can add images using the imageView property of a cell:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
```

in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Comment: yeah i also added to resources file.

Comment: yeah sure. its displayed. but image is shown in front of text. text is not displayed fully.

Comment: in that case you need to use a custom cell, subclassing the UITableViewCell class. You can follow a tutorial like this one: http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/ or searching for "custom uitableviewcell"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example cell loading a facebook image in a table cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Leave cells empty if there's no data yet
    if (nodeCount > 0)
    {
        // Set up the cell...
        AppRecord *appRecord = [self.friendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = friend.name;

        // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
        if (!appRecord.icon)
        {
            // set the url
            appRecord.imageURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", friend.recordID];

            // request the download
            if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];                
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = appRecord.icon;
        }

    }

    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

you adding it right, but you fogot one thing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
    [imv release];

    //you fogot this:
    return cell;
     }
```

Comment: it won't work because you already has `return cell;` above ;)

Comment: oh... at the end of this line, yes. then just replace it.

Comment: i just edited. the problem was in this: you returned uncompleted cell to tableView. I mean you returned it first,  then added image, so it was ignored

Comment: oh nice. thanks for reply. the image is displayed. but it shown in front of text. the text is hide. how to split the text and image

Comment: try Matteo Alessani solution (upvoted answer on this question). If it will not help, you will need to add your own labels, insteed of usual labels, just like you added image.

Answer (score 0):

// create a rectangle box for image view

```
UIImageView *iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
iconImage.frame = CGRectMake(12,4,53.5,53.5);

// Create a label for cells
UILabel *cellName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,18,200,20)];
cellName.font = [self fontForBodyTextStyle];

NSString *cellNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.tableCellNames[indexPath.row]];

// Select path row tab actions
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:

        cellName.text = cellNameStr;
        iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"condition.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];

        break;

    case 1:
       cellName.text = cellNameStr;
        iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"videos.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];
        break;

    case 2:
        cellName.text = cellNameStr;
        iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"provider.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];
        break;

    case 3:
        cellName.text = cellNameStr;
        iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];
        break;

    default:
        NSAssert(NO, @"Unhandled value in cellForRowAtIndexPath");
        break;
}
```

Thank VKJ,