# Print a specific value from ios UITABLEVIEW

Tags: ios6

```
SOffer[26229:c07] current Product: (
    {
        id = 20;
        image = "img2.png";
        name = "offer 2";
    }
)
```

I have product which result the above when I print it through NSLog,, I need to print the these individually. Following code generate this

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }
        NSString *currentProductName;
        currentProductName = [productKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        currentProduct = [products objectForKey:[productKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"current Product: %@",currentProduct);
        //currentProductName = [currentProduct objectForKey:@"image"];
        //currentProduct = [currentProduct ];

        [[cell textLabel] setText:currentProductName];

    return cell;
    }
```

currentProduct is declared as NSArray but when i try to print with objectForKey it say No visible interface for NSArray declares the selector ObjectForKey

Comment: `objectForKey` i believe works with `NSDictionary` only. `NSArray` does not have key value pairs. Unless `currentProduct` holds the JSON file, then you gonna have to first get out the Array Object of the first Product and assign it to a `NSDictionary`, where you can then use the `objectForKey` to get your image value

Comment: thanks, how i will extract the id, name and image separately from array?

Comment: Look at the answer I posted

Comment: NSDictionary *cp = [products objectForKey:[productKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; I did this way, it compile good but terminate execution with this message in console -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759d140

Comment: seems like your `objectForKey` is receiving a value that is not expected. Separate your two calls into different lines and do a `NSLog` to see if those are the values you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectForKey`, I believe works with `NSDictionary` only.

`NSArray` does not have key value pairs. Unless `currentProduct` holds the JSON file, then you gonna have to first get out the Array Object of the first Product and assign it to a `NSDictionary`, where you can then use the `objectForKey` to get your image value.

Something like this:

```
// Get the first product object from the NSArray. Assuming you dropped your entire Product values into a NSArray
NSMutableDictionary *prodDict = [currentProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSString *prodID = [prodDict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *prodName = [prodDict objectForKey:@"name"];
...
```

Comment: thanks alot, can you guide me a bit more how i will display the image in the cell?

Comment: you are better off looking at this post on how to add a `UIImage` to the `TableView` as this is a bit of a long explanation that deserves its own post.  Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148260/how-to-add-images-to-uitableview-cell